# Silverlight Grid Layout

Tags: silverlight, grid

When I have Grid in Silverlight, and I provide Column Definitions like below

```
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>            
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

For some reason the items that get placed in those columns get cut off.
That is I only see half the control.
But when I do

```
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

and put items in those respected rows I can see the entire items with their proper respective widths and heights.

What could I be overlooking?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions> 
    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition> 
    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>             
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

is actually just a short cut for

```
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

which means, you have two columns in this Grid, each takes 50% of the width.

Same way,

```
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>         
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>         
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>         
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

is the same as

```
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.5*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.5*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score -1):

Look for following link. It should help you:

[Using the Grid control in Silverlight](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Using-the-Grid-control-in-Silverlight-2-Beta-1.aspx)